# Oracle ODP.NET Timeout exception

Tags: c#, oracle, timeout, odp.net

I'm using ODP.NET in an c# application, and i'm using the following code to execute a stored procedure:

```
OracleCommand _cmd = new OracleCommand();
        try
        {
            _cmd.CommandTimeout = 900;
            _cmd.Connection = myConnection;
            _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            _cmd.CommandText = storedProcedureName;

            _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DisplayAnyway = true;
            ImportMessage = "General problem occured\n" + ex.Message;
            ex.ToString();
        }
```

My question is, how could i modify this in order to be able to do some special stuff only when a timeout exception occurs. The odp.net seems to have only a OracleException and no OracleTimeoutException or somthing like this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `Code`/`ErrorCode` properties of [OracleException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleexception.code.aspx) in order to see if you can use them for discriminating the specific error.

Answer (score 1):

The ODP.NET's `OracleException` class has a `Number` property that should contain the Oracle specific error number: [OracleException's Number Property](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleExceptionClass.htm#i1008138)